# Enviar variables por GET con HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"?

Tags: php, formularios, get, http-get, meta-tags

Tengo un formulario simple que envía variables por método GET a una página en PHP:

```
   <form name="formulario" method="get" action="pag1.php">
    <input type="tel" name="tel" value="">
    <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
```

La estructura de **"pag1.php"** contiene una etiqueta `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="35;URL=pag2.php">` ya que necesito que esta página sea visible solo una cantidad de tiempo especifica para que posteriormente redirija a **"pag2.php"**

¿Cómo puedo recuperar en **"pag2.php"** lo que viene de **"pag1.php"** `$tel = $_GET['tel'];` cumpliendo la función de tiempo que me da la etiqueta `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="35;URL=pag2.php">`

Estoy pensando en algo así:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT='35;URL=https://kewhats.com/processtwo/?tel'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo siguiente funcionó para mí:

```
$tel2 = $_GET['tel'];
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT='35;URL=pag2.php?tel2=$teld2'>";
```